# How can I expand partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I Installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS next to Windows 10. I decided to increase my Ubuntu partition because I don't have enough space for apps, So i went to Windows 10 and shrink my larger Partition and now I have 50 GB of unallocated space.. So my question is:

How can I safely expand my Ubuntu partion using this unallocated space? I also have a bootable pendrive with Ubuntu .iso
["nieprzydzielone" means unallocated, sorry, gparted is in Polish, the Orange one is the partition I want to expand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1C2zJ.png)

Comment: Add a current-window-only screenshot of `gparted` /dev/sda to your original question, and I'll take a look for you. You'll need a Ubuntu Live DVD to manage the partition. If you don't already have one, burn one now.

Comment: @heynnema look at my screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or loose data.

The use of an extended partition (sda3) makes this a little difficult. I'll outline the easiest way first, and we can add more to the procedure if we have to.

Keep these things in mind:

- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower part of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot the a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted` or run the following command to open `gparted`:

  ```
  sudo -i gparted &
  ```

## Step #1

- right-click on sda5 and select **swapoff**
- right-click on sda3 and select **resize**
- **resize** the left side of sda3 all the way to the left

  - it may be difficult to grab the left side of sda3, if so, STOP here
- you'll see that the unallocated space is now used by sda3
- close the **move/resize** window
- click the Apply icon

## Step #2

- right-click on sda5 and select **swapoff** (already done in Step #1)
- right-click on sda5 and select **move**
- note (write down) the numeric partition size before the **move**
- **move** sda5 all the way to the left (inside of sda3)

  - be carefull not to resize sda5. If you do, cancel and start Step #2 again
- close the **move/resize** window
- click the Apply icon

## Step #3

- right-click on sda6 and select **resize**
- **resize** the left side of sda6 all the way to the left
- close the **move/resize** window
- click the Apply icon
- this may take a while so be patient
- right-click on sda5 and select **swapon**

Now quit gparted and reboot your computer, being sure to remove the USB flash pen at the appropriate time.

Comment: So I just have to resize sda3 and sda6 will expand itself?

Comment: Wait until my answer is completed...

Comment: @DanielDutkowski  Now my answer is complete.

Comment: I cannot pass first step because sda 3 is busy and I can't resize this (I'm using live USB at the moment) Should I swapoff Linux-swap first?

Comment: Yes, swapoff sda5. I'll update my procedure.

Comment: In step #2 should I drag rectangle by pressing the frame of this rectangle all the way to the left and not click the left arrow?

Comment: You're going to **move** sda5, so make sure that you have a hand cursor, by pointing at the center of sda5. If you accidentally resize sda5 to the left, then resize the right side of sda5 left, setting the partition size to the same size as it was before... (so note the partition size BEFORE you do anything).